# How to set Data Validation formulas in Excel for a specific column

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, invalid-characters

I have an Excel 2010 sheet that content editors use for rewriting urls. Of course certain characters aren't allowed to be entered but they do it anyway.So I want to set a rule on this.

Let's for simplicity just take spaces.

I select the column in question, go to Data>Data Validation, select Allow>Custom and as the formula enter SUM(IFCOUNT(" "))>0. This doesn't work, it generates an error on every value in that column, even if it doesn't have any spaces in it. I also, for spaces, used TRIM(), SUBSTITUTE(" ", "") but they all lead to the same result.

So, what would be the best way to prevent a user to enter or add a space, or any other illegal character, in a cell in a specific column in an Excel sheet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the options you can implement (using VBA). Regarding restricting user Inputs I would personally use UserForms over direct input into the worksheets as in UserForms you have more control over what users can and what they cannot do.

```
Public bUpdate As Boolean
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If bUpdate = False Then 'avoid infinite loop
        bUpdate = True 'flag start

        Dim sCharacters() As Variant
            sCharacters = Array(" ", ",", ".")'list of Invalid Characters
        Dim sItem As Variant

        For Each sItem In sCharacters
            Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, sItem, vbNullString)
        Next sItem

        bUpdate = False 'flag process ended
    End If
End Sub
```